# Load a local file into bigquery with php

Tags: php, google-bigquery

Looking to load a local file into bigquery using the google-php-api, so far I am using:

```
    $load = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfigurationLoad();
    $load->setDestinationTable($table);
    $load->setSourceUris()
    $load->setSourceFormat('NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON');
    $load->setMaxBadRecords(1);

    $config = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfiguration();
    $config->setLoad($load);

    $job = new Google_Service_Bigquery_Job();
    $job->setConfiguration($config);
    $job->setKind('load');

    return $this->service->jobs->insert(PROJECT, $job);
```

The problem I am running into is that

```
$load->setSourceUris()
```

Will only accept a google storage uri, and I'd like to use a local file. Alternatively I can stream multiple rows into bigquery at a time, however I would like to just load a file or "bulk insert" is there a go to way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load only files that are uploaded to Google Cloud Storage, you cannot upload local files. You need to upload first the file to GCS.

You can stream the files contents from a local file in batches.

Comment: While I don't mind streaming, what would the recommended batch size be per request? I need to insert an average of 60000 per minute and want to make sure I make it as optimal as possible

Comment: You can run jobs in parallel, there are strict limits to streaming insert see here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#quota there is not much a place to tune, you have HTTP request size limit.